# I have application number and attorney docket number, but I could not find application status on the USPTO website

Tags: patent-applications, status, pair

Our lawyers filed a patent on April 20th, 2021. I need to see the status of it on the USPTO website. I tried searching on public pair using the application number.

https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

I am unable to find it. Is there any way I see it?  I need to extract that information. I am thinking to use that as proof of application submission.

Comment: Can’t you just ask your lawyer?

Answer (score 1):

It will be visible now in Private PAIR to the attorney who filed it, but *not* visible to the public in Public PAIR until it is published at the 18 month point unless early publication was requested. Or not until grant if non-publication was requested.